# How to highlight selected routerLink text on page reload, in Polymer3.x ?

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, app-route

I am building a Polymer3 music app, which fetches playlists from public api. All the playlistNames are implemented as routerLinks.

On clicking, the `playlistName` is getting bold, but **on page reload the routerLink is not highlighted**(bold).

For example: If i am entering `localhost:8081/playlist1` in URL, then playlist1 should be bold, on page reload.

Thanks in advance.

[image: routerLinks not highlighted]

```js
static get template() {
    return html `

      <app-location route="{{route}}" url-space-regex="^[[rootPath]]">
      </app-location>

      <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="[[rootPath]]:page" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subroute}}">
      </app-route>

      <app-drawer-layout fullbleed="" narrow="{{narrow}}">
        <!-- Drawer content -->
        <app-drawer id="drawer" slot="drawer" swipe-open="[[narrow]]">
          <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
          <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[playlists]]">
              <a name="[[item.name]]" href="[[rootPath]][[item.name ]]">[[item.name]]</a>
            </template>
          </iron-selector>
        </app-drawer>

    `;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> On clicking, the playlistName is getting bold, but on page reload the
>   routerLink is not highlighted(bold).

This happens probably because of [IronSelectableBehaviour](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-selector/behaviors/Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior) present in the `iron-selector` element, which I believe applies the bold style `on-tap`. This also happens for `paper-tabs` for example.

So, the bold style is being applied because you're tapping the item. However, if you go to a page directly through the URL, you didn't actually click the item, that's why you're not getting the same behaviour.

**Solution:**

You will always have the class `iron-selected` on the current active item, whether through URL or on tap.

From the [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-selector):

> iron-selector is not styled. Use the `iron-selected` CSS class to style
>   the selected element.

Try it out

```
  <style>
    .iron-selected {
      background: #eee;
    }
  </style>
```